# Google Says not to use Thunderbird. why not?

Tags: thunderbird

Newbie here.  On my third day of trying to install Thunderbird.  Apparently, it no longer works with Gmail.   Google sends back a message (via webmail) saying not to install it because the security is inferior.  Has anybody else come across this?

Feeling quite grumpy because I thought installing Thunderbird from the Ubuntu Software center would be a piece of cake.  I'm ready to throw in the towel after repeated attempts deleting Thunderbird and reinstalling it over and over again and trying to connect to Gmail.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Argh!  I really wanted an alternative to Windows.  It's not working.

Comment: I don't see why Thunderbird would be less secure than other MUAs. There are no serious publicly known security vulnerabilities and when there are, they're fixed quickly.

Comment: This is about Google encouraging clients to use OAuth 2 that Google thinks is more secure, not about specific security related bugs/design flaws of Thunderbird itself.

Comment: @NGRhodes: Yes, that makes sense, though as far as I understand two-factor authentication, it is only more secure compared to weak, re-used passwords on malware-ridden systems in the hands of users, who submit their auth data to every phishing attack, which would make it more secure for the majority of users and devices, so at least I can understand, where Google is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the link below and allow access to "less secure apps". Now Thunderbird will work.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Google would say that, but I've been using Thunderbird with Google mail, for about 3 years now, and never had an issue.

[image]